# Нужно ли ставить тире, если пропущено слово?

Tags: тире

Подскажите, стоит ли ставить тире в предложении:
*Более 100 семинаров в год, из них более 70 (—) бесплатно*?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По **[5-му пункту §6 «Тире в неполном предложении»](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91)**, тире ставится при пропущенной части **только в том случае, если есть пауза**. Делаем выводы:

*Более 100 семинаров в год, из них более 70 бесплатно* — паузы нет;

*Более 100 семинаров в год, из них более 70 — бесплатно* — а здесь пауза стоит.

Решение зависит от интонации автора. Именно автор решает, ставить тире или нет.